# Difference between R and Q in numbers

Tags: number-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

I am an ICSE student and I have some problem in mathematics regarding linear inequations.

In some examples I have found x $\in$ R  and I have also found x $\in$ Q .

I know that 'R' means rational numbers, but can anybody explain me what is 'Q' and which numbers are allowed ? Are both of them similar or is there some difference between the two ?

Also, please tell me the difference between I and Z.

Comment: Generally speaking, $\mathbb R$ refers to the real numbers, $\mathbb Q$ refers to the rationals, and $\mathbb Z$ refers to the integers.  I don't think $I$ or $\mathbb I$ is standard.  I don't think it's ever good to use $R$ for the rationals, as people will interpret it as referring to the reals.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Q}$ is used for the rational numbers because they are q-uotient integers. I have seen mostly $I$ to represent an interval for example $[0,1]$, and not the Integers.

Comment: $R$ stands for $\Bbb R$, the field of real numbers. $Q$ stands for $\Bbb Q=Quot(\Bbb Z)$, the quotient field of the integers $\Bbb Z$. Here the $Z$ comes from the German word "Zahlen" (ganze Zahlen - integers).